# How to convert gif to text, for inline access from a tk script?

Tags: tcl, gif, tk-toolkit

I saw the following code in the famous tkdiff utility:

```
image create photo rediffImage -format gif -data {
R0lGODdhFAAUAPf/AAAAAIAAAACAAICAAAAAgIAAgACAgMDAwMDcwKbK8P/w1P/isf/Ujv/G
......
}
```

I have a gif image to include in my tk script. How can I convert it to data like this so that I don't have to call the separate gif file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's base64 data. Tcl 8.6 includes a command for doing the conversion.

```
# Read the data in *as binary data*
set f [open yourfile.gif b]
set data [read $f]
close $f

# Do the encoding
set encodedData [binary encode base64 $data]

# Print the encoded version out; it's just plain ASCII text now
puts $encodedData
```

Note that you can add whatever whitespace you want to base64 data; it remains valid. This means that you can split up and indent the lines however you see fit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But due to some reason gif images are coming up invisible in the tk widget, but pnm images are coming up fine. Is there a way to do the same thing for pnm files ? The command (image create photo rediffImage -format pnm)  - says pnm format unsupported.